# Ruby on Rails: passing in a variable to an active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This question relates to a RoR quiz app.  I am looking to display the results of the quiz, showing both the correct answer as well as the user's answer.

Therefore, in my view, I need to loop through each question and show the question answer, as well as the user's answer.  However, I am struggling trying to figure out how to correctly query the user's answer.

To query the user_answer, I need the response_set where the user_id = current_user.id and I need to pass in the question_id as it loops through the each loop. However, I'm stuck on how to accomplish this.

What do I need to do to show the user_answer in the view alongside the correct_answer?

**I have 3 models:**

```
Response_set
belongs_to :user
has_many :responses

Reponse
belongs_to :response_set
belongs_to :question

Question
has_many :responses
```

**Table fields:**

```
create_table :response_sets do |t|
  t.integer :user_id

create_table :responses do |t|
  t.integer :response_set_id
  t.integer :question_id
  t.integer :user_answer

create_table :questions do |t|
  t.integer :correct_answer
```

**Controller**

```
@questions = Question.all
@user = current_user.id
```

**View (just looping through the questions and not displaying the user's answer)**

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
   <%= question.correct_answer %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is really ambiguous if you ask me

Comment: I think this might be a case for named scopes, but as a Rails noob I can't really offer a complete solution.

Comment: Do you have a `current_user` method or something? How do you know for which user to show the response?

Comment: Yes, I have a current user method.  I'll add that to my question. In the controller: `@user = current_user.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mentor ended up solving this one for me.  Here is the solution that he presented:

> "I think a better approach here would be get the responses from the
>   response set and loop over that instead of looping over the
>   questions."

**Controller:**

```
 @response_set = Response_set.where("user_id = ?", @user).includes({:responses => :question}).last
```

**View:**

```
 <% @response_set.responses.each do |response| %>
   <%= response.question.correct_answer %>
   <%= response.user_answer %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add user_id in responses table, this way you don't have to query response_set table.
After this you can do something like this inside the loop

```
 question.responses.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first.user_answer
```

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear, but in my attempt to simplify my question, I left out that there is also a Test model. As there can be different tests, and a user can take multiple tests, it is necessary to keep the user_id in the response_set. Response_set belongs_to :test

Comment: As response belongs_to response_set and response_set belongs_to user.    You can have user_id in both the tables(response and response_set), there is no harm in that.